# Alteração de DNS usado por um domínio

Tags: dns, domínio

Tenho um domínio X que usa dois NS, um master e outro slave1, do datacenter Equinix aqui no Brasil.

Vou alterar esse domínio para usar outros NS da Amazon, quanto tempo demora para fazer efeito?

Durante este tempo, toda requisição vai continuar caindo no "apontamento" antigo dos NS antigos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Propagação**

A propagação dos nameservers pode demorar até 24 horas e depende de diversos factores. 
Entre eles está o seu ISP e o [TTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live) (time to live ou tempo de vida) definido no registo.

**Requisições**

Durante o processo de propagação as requisições que efectuar irão retornar uma resposta conforme o registo actual nos servidores de DNS mais perto de si.
Portanto todas as respostas vão ser dadas com base nos nameservers antigos, até a propagação estar concluída e poderá haver discrepâncias entre diversos servidores de DNS o que é completamente natural. Ou seja o mesmo domínio poderá apontar para dois servidores distintos em locais diferentes. Também poderá acontecer de um ISP demorar mais um pouco para ter os nameservers completamente propagados.

Por norma costumo efectuar a alteração ao final da tarde de sexta feira, pois dependendo do ramo de negócio do domínio o mesmo poderá não ter o mesmo uso durante o fim de semana.

Se migrar o site para outro servidor aconselho a passar todo o conteúdo sujeito a mudanças no final da propagação (emails, base de dados, entre outros dados dinâmicos)

[Site para consultar o estando actual da propagação do dominio](https://www.whatsmydns.net/)

Comment: É exatamente isso que irei fazer, migrar site de um servidor para outro. Você está me dizendo que eu devo deixar o site já pronto no "destino" mas ainda conectado no banco de dados antigo, e só alterar essa configuração após o final da propagação?

Comment: Se puder estabelecer a ligação com a base de dados no servidor antigo sim, facilitará o seu trabalho. Pois bastará migrar a base de dados antiga no final da propagação para o destino. Evitando fazer uma fusão das duas.

Comment: Excelente sugestão! Se você tivesse cerca de 40 subdomínios neste domínio, cada um com seu banco de dados, você iria parar o sistema inteiro e migrar todos os BDs ou iria parar um subdomínio por vez para migra-lo?

Comment: Eu sei que nesta questões o cliente quer sempre o serviço pronto para ontem, mas de qualquer modo faria a migração faseada por questões de organização e prevenção. É mais demorado mas eu prefiro. Também temos de ter em conta se os dois servidores possuem paineis de administração iguais ( WHM/CPANEL, PLESK, INTERWORX, entre outros). Também poderá fazer o mesmo com os A records.